# Take a screenshot of a webpage in Nodejs/javascript and upload it to discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm trying to develop a discord bot. I have it so when a command is called "opgg examplename" it will search the example name on the website op.gg. I want it to be able to take a screenshot of that webpage given, and attach it in discord. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any solution to your problem, But I know what you want to do and I have an alternative. If you want to create a bot to get information about lol player stats I recommend any scrape/crawler to get the info from site, them use this info to make any visualisation with your desing and send in discord.

Remember to that riot has public api, you can make the request direct to riot, after process the data, generate any visualization and send in discord.

Comment: Ah I see, frankly I have no idea how but I will look into it. Thank you!!